# Generate correct import using protoc in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm using `proto3` in my `python` project. Everything work good but when I generate classes from `proto` files import is not correct.

I have directory structure like this.

```
project/endpoints/protos -> image.proto
```

I want output files in.

project/endpoints/grpc -> generated classes from proto files

I'm using this command to generate classes from `proto` files.

```
python -m grpc.tools.protoc \
    --include_imports \
    --include_source_info \
    --proto_path=project/endpoints/protos \
    --python_out=project/endpoints/grpc \
    --grpc_python_out=project/endpoints/grpc \
    image.proto
```

I also tried it with `python3 ....` but same result.

it generate the files in `project/endpoints/grpc` but problem is the import is not correct. When I see import it look like.

```
import image_pb2 as image__pb2
```

But it should be like this.

```
import project.endpoints.grpc.image_pb2 as image__pb2
```

Can you please let me know how to generate import like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much research

i found it
[in here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1491#issuecomment-562524136)

Solution in Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install 2to3
```

run to adjust the imports:

```
2to3 path/of/generated -w -n
```

so

```
import image_pb2
```

will change to

```
from . import image_pb2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need:

```
from project.endpoints.grpc import image_pb2 as image__pb2
```

You should write this in the proto file:

```
import "project/endpoints/grpc/image.proto"
```

And then set the current directory or `--proto_path` to the parent of "project".